# How to do conditional row summation in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2d array that includes positive entries and -1 values those are the missing values. I want to sum the rows of this matrix without including the -1 values. Is there any way to perform conditional row summation in numpy?

Comment: Look at masked arrays, maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Approach #1: multiply by a boolean array, which works because `True` behaves as 1 and `False` as 0:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  3,  0,  4,  2],
       [ 2,  1,  4, -1,  1],
       [-1,  2,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  1,  2]])
>>> (a * (a != -1)).sum(axis=1)
array([10,  8, 14, 16,  9])
```

Approach #2: use the same boolean array (well, flipped -- before we wanted to know which ones to keep, and now which ones to ignore) as a formal mask for a `MaskedArray`.

```
>>> am = np.ma.MaskedArray(a, mask=(a==-1))
>>> am
masked_array(data =
 [[1 3 0 4 2]
 [2 1 4 -- 1]
 [-- 2 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 0]
 [0 2 4 1 2]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False False]
 [False False False  True False]
 [ True False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> am.sum(axis=1)
masked_array(data = [10 8 14 16 9],
             mask = [False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

[To be honest, though, I almost never use `MaskedArray`.]